# Agora unity sdk is not letting the scene to render with MRTK Oculus Integration

Tags: unity-game-engine, video-streaming, agora.io, oculus, quest

I am building an *oculus app* using *MRTK* (Mixed reality toolkit) and need *Agora's* video feed streaming capabilities.

While building my app I am able to hear sound but **not able to see unity scene**, it's all blank and appears as a black screen.

Has anyone encountered this before?

I did try Agora SDK with oculus integration without MRTK and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

yes change the project settings xr-Plug in management to oculus for android.